# NodeJs express-validator. Case sensitive checking json

Tags: node.js, case-sensitive, express-validator

I'm writing a NodeJS application. 
I'm trying to validate the input json using 'express-validator':

```
var express = require('express');
const winston = require('../config/winston');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const myController= require('../controller/myController.js');
var router = express.Router();

router.use(       [
              check('COMMON.user','User incorrect').not().isEmpty(),          
          ],
           (req, res, next) => {                
      const resCheck = validationResult(req);
      if (!resCheck.isEmpty()) {
          obj= req.body;
          obj.COMMON= {codigoRespuesta:-1, textoRespuesta:"Error checking request"};

          winston.info(JSON.stringify(obj));
         return res.json(obj);        
      }else{
          console.log("vacio");
      }
      return myController.procesaRequest(req, res); 
});
```

+
Seems "**check**" method is case-sensitive. If json input contains "*{common: {user:"Test"...*" throws error, but "*{COMMON: {user:"Test"...*"  works ok.

How can i make 'check" case insensitive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why You need case insensitive check, cause api-s have to be strict about validation.

But I recommend You to transform `common` to `COMMON` to achieve Your goal:

```
router.use(
  // transforming (adapting)
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body && req.body['common']) {
      req.body['COMMON'] = Object.create(req.body['common']);
      delete req.body['common'];
    }
    next();
  },

  // validation
  [
    check('COMMON.user', 'User incorrect').not().isEmpty(),
  ],

  // post-validation
  (req, res, next) => {                
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      winston.info(JSON.stringify(req.body), errors.array());
      return res.status(400).json({
        codigoRespuesta: -1, 
        textoRespuesta: "Error checking request",
        errors: errors.array()
      });        
    }
    next();
  },

  // handler
  myController.procesaRequest
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if clients will be using upper case when calling to the API or not... Your answer works fin. Thanks!

Comment: :) for such things people invented documentations, manuals, swagger, open api reference and etc. with examples